# Persistent copy&paste for jstree nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, copy-paste, jstree

The default way to set up copy&paste with jstree as described in [the documentation](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/crrm) is easy enough and works well, but only within the scope  of JavaScript variables context of the loaded page.

Specifically, if I select copy and then paste that will work. However, if I select copy, then reload the page, paste will not work since the data about copy is lost now.

How can I make this work? I guess something will need to be stored and retrieved from a cookie. Where do I find that? Also, is there an existing option in the plugin for this use case?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your audience, I would try to implement a copy/paste through html5 local storage.  For some simple text copying and such it should be fairly easy to implement.

Html 5 local storage is just a key:value pair that is stored on the users local web browser memory.  Therefore it'll be maintained through a web browser reload.  Heck it even should be able to be saved if they accidentally close out of the browser completely!

I think with a little javascript, and if you use a library like JQuery, it shouldn't be too hard to implement.  You could even have the added benefit of multiple copies enabled as you could just have multiple key:value pairs.

Take a look at a tutorial I found that I think is pretty good to get an idea of how to start with it:

http://paperkilledrock.com/2010/05/html5-localstorage-part-one/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you can write a new plugin for jstree to get this done.

Take a look [here](http://static.jstree.com/v.1.0pre/jquery.jstree.js) to see how the current [CRRM Plugin](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/crrm) is implemented.(CRRM plugin is included by default with jstree. Serach for CRRM in the above linked file if you find it difficult to locate the place).

I guess you can take a look how it is implemented and implement the methods in a similar way but with persistence.